# SQL How to list the NULL values once output is generated for another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, spring, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL and I am having the below doubt-

3 tables:

```
mysql> describe course;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| course_id | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| title     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dept_name | varchar(20 ) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| credits   | decimal(2,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


mysql> describe section;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| course_id    | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| sec_id       | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| semester     | varchar(6)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| year         | decimal(4,0) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| building     | varchar(15)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| room_number  | varchar(7)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time_slot_id | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| capacity     | int(11)      | YES  |     | 30      |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe department;
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_name | varchar(20)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| building  | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| budget    | decimal(12,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The question is **"List the total number of sections is being offered by each department in Spring 2008."**

I have tried the below query:

```
 SELECT dept_name,SUM(sec_id) AS Total_offerings 
 FROM section natural 
 left outer join course 
 WHERE semester='Spring' and year=2008 
 GROUP By dept_name;
```

But the result does not contains the department names with Null values.

Can anyone help me in how to add the department names in the output even if they were not taught in Spring 2008 with NULL values

```
The output looks like this:
+-------------+----------------+
| dept_name   | total_offering |
+-------------+----------------+
| Accounting  | 7              |
| Astronomy   | 4              |
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with sql server and sql server 2008? It looks like you are using mysql?

Answer (score 1):

For `LEFT JOIN` You need to put the filter on the join condition otherwise is just a normal `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT dept_name, COUNT(sec_id) AS Total_offerings 
FROM department
JOIN course 
  ON  department.dept_name = course.dept_name
LEFT JOIN section
  ON section.course_id = course.course_id
 AND section.semester = 'Spring'
 AND section.year = 2008
GROUP By dept_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL use IFNULL and for SQL Server use ISNULL

```
SELECT ISNULL(dept_name,'Blank Dept Name'),SUM(sec_id) AS Total_offerings     
FROM section natural left outer join course WHERE semester='Spring' and year=2008 
GROUP By ISNULL(dept_name,'Blank Dept Name');
```